# PHP call to WCF - soap header issue

Tags: php, wcf, soap

I am making some PHP application and I want to use my WCF service, which is working good. I need to make soap call, and set header to something like this:

```
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">GetPage</a:Action>
<a:MessageID>1</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo>
  <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://someurl.com</a:To>
```

In my php file where I want to make the call I have:

```
$ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing'; //Namespace of the WS.
//Body of the Soap Header.
$headerbody = array('MessageID' => '1',
                    'Action' => 'GetPage',
                    'To' => 'http://someurl.com');  

//Create Soap Header.
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, $headerbody);

//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$GetPageResponse = $soapClient->GetPage($GetPageRequest);
```

When I go to the logs of my service, I see that the message that came in looks like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Flow/2012/10">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1"      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://someurl.com</To>
<Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:Flow/2012/10/GetPage</Action>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

$GetPageRequest is for now irrelevant. So, in my header there is no MessageID. What am I missing here? Did I set something wrong? Also, how to correctly set part 'ReplyTo'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why MessageID is not getting through in your output yet, but adding ReplyTo->Address is as simple as adding an sub-array to your header array.

```
$headerbody = array('MessageID' => '1',
                'Action' => 'GetPage',
                'To' => 'http://someurl.com',
                'ReplyTo' => array (
                      'Address' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous'
                      )
                 );
```

Comment: Yep, I supposed that it would be something like that, thanks! Me neither, didn't find the problem, really strange thing..